# Reduction gulp - node_modules folder for git repository

Tags: git, github, gulp, node-modules

I have a `node_modules` folder that contains 30mb of gulp modules. I want to reduce the size, possibly by deleting some libraries, and add `node_modules` to my git repository.

Is it possible to delete libraries from `node_modules` using gulp without any problems?

Comment: Where your node_modules directory contains your dependencies, chances are that you cannot go in and delete anything. You can try deleting the directory outright and re-running `npm install` to see if there was anything extra in there.

Comment: Thanks for help. I got folder, that have size 161kb! It's git difference! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

You can't reduce / delete from your libraries when your `node_modules` directory contains your dependencies. You can delete the directory outright and re-run `npm install` to see anything extra in there.